# php storm move statement up down configuration

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using php storm on a mac.
To move a selection up or down (move statement up/down), the shortcut is cmd + up/down.

If you press this shortcut multiple times that's fine.

But sometimes you just want  to hold the shortcut down and see the selection going up or down.
(It saves you from typing the shorcut multiple times).

The problem I founded is that in this case where you hold the shortcut down : there is too much time
between the moment where you push the shortcut and the moment where php storm understood that you want a "holding shortcut" operation.

Is there a setting to customize this time please ?
I didn't find it.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows, it's probably Mac specific. Can you check [if this helps](http://lifehacker.com/5826055/make-your-keyboard-keys-repeat-properly-when-held-down-in-mac-os-x-lion)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know about that bug. But it doesn't help on reducing the latency of the shortcuts. That's not something horrible, it's less than 1 second, but it's clearly improvable area to my opinion, as a front end user.